# Is is possible to have a third point C on this circle, so that A,B,C all fairly placed?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Consider a circle with radius $3$ and centre at the origin. 
>   Points $A$ and $B$ have coordinates $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$, respectively.
>
> If a dart is thrown
>   at the circle, then assuming a uniform distribution, it is clear that
>   the probabilities of the following two events are equal:
>
> - The dart is closer to A than to B
> - The dart is closer to B than to A
>
> Is it possible to have a third point C on this circle, so that all
>   $A, B, C$ are fairly placed?

What's the key to solving this question? I have tried to express the areas in terms of the coordinates of C but failed.

Comment: You want there to be a $1/3$ probability that it is closest to each?

Comment: Consider the line bisector $L$ of $A$ and $B$. Then a point $M$ is closer to $A$ than $B$ if it is on the same side of $L$ as $A$. I hope this helps (not completely sure about the solution of the problem)

Comment: So perhaps I can find C on the bisector pf AB, and the area of the bisector formed by the bisector AC, BC is 1/3? (not sure too)

Comment: I draw a figure and it seems doable. I have no time to check the details of computation now, I hope I can do it later. The problem is interesting to me. Where does it come from?

Comment: It is from "The Art and Craft of Problem Solving"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p_A$ be the probability that $A$ is the nearest point, and so on.

These probabilities are proportional to the [Voronoi areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

Assume $C$ is at $(0,y)$,  then by symmetry $p_B=p_A$

If $C$ is at $(0,2)$ then clearly $p_C < p_A$

If $C$ is at $(0,0)$ then clearly $p_C > p_A$

Because the probabilities (areas) are continuous on $y$, then there must be some $0<y<2$ such that $p_C=p_A=p_B$

[image]

Comment: Is there another solution where $C = (x, y)$ with $x > 0$?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated I don't think so. Moving the point to the right makes the green area decrease and the blue one increase.